# use euro symbol (or any symbol) for emacs keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, unicode

I set up this duplicate line function: https://kundeveloper.com/blog/duplicate-line/

and bound it to the euro symbol like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-€") 'duplicate-line)
```

And it worked (for a while).  On my keyboard, left alt + right alt + 4.

However, all of a sudden, when I restarted, it started to give me the following error:

[image]

```
error: M- must prefix a single character, not \342\202\254
```

and when I look in my `init.el` file, it also looks likes this

[image]

but if I copy that from `init.el` and paste it into stack overflow (as I did at the start of this question) I get the € back!

Does anybody know what I might have changed about my emacs or ubuntu to stop it accepting € as a key?

btw I still get this nice message when I try to use it:

[image]

Comment: Have you changed your preferences related to the preferred coding system recently? I assume that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: No, not that I know of

Comment: Maybe you've changed your locale, or some update has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make sure that your `locale` (as set from where you launch Emacs) is a utf-8 locale.  As a workaround you can also put `;; -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the first line of your file.  In Emacs-26, none of that should be needed because Elisp files are presumed to be utf-8 regardless of locale.

Comment: I am using emacs 26.  Not sure what changed.  This worked great though.